# How to get tenant properties through PowerShell with SharePointPnP?

Tags: powershell, office365, sharepoint-online

I have been given a task to setup a scheduled task which will run daily to pull down the list of allowed domains from SPO.  This is not an issue if I use Connect-SPOService and Get-SPOTenant, like this:

Connect-SPOService –url https://xxxx-admin.sharepoint.com
Get-SPOTenant | select -ExpandProperty SharingAllowedDomainList > d:\allowedDomains.txt

The issue issue is that this has to be automated.  There is also a requirement to use an ClientId and Secret  in the script, rather than providing me with an account which bypasses MFA and has SP Admin rights.

Because of that, I've turned to SharePointPnP, which does allow you to connect with ClientId and Secret. I'm able to connect to connect with the following:

Connect-PnPOnline -url https://xxxx-admin.sharepoint.com -ClientId "xxxxx" -ClientSecret "xxxxx"

Where I'm struggling now is trying to how I can retrieve the SharingAllowedDomainList property through SharePointPnP, or if that is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

@THTX,

Can you please have a try below pnp powershell cmdlet?

> [Get-PnPTenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnptenant?view=sharepoint-ps)
> [Get-PnPTenantSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnptenantsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

It has `SharingAllowedDomainList` property:

[image]

BR